# How to get rid of the default background of the Android DatePickerDialog in Android 4.4.4?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project targeting *API 25* and having *API 19* as the minimum SDK, in one of the activities when a button is touched the following [`DatePickerDialog`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/date_picker/) appears:

[image]

As you can see, I defined a custom drawable with rounded corner and used it in the DatePickerDialog. **The issue is that I can't get rid of the default background that has a shadowed border when running my application on an Android 4.4.4 device(API 19).**

On Android N device (API 25) everything seem to work properly, here is a screenshot:

[image]

I would like to know how to remove the default background in Android 4.4.4 devices, is there any useful xml style attribute? Or maybe a programmatic solution? I can't find any resource discussing this issue.

### Details

#### `DatePickerFragment` implementation that I am using:

```
public class DatePickerFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment, 
    Android.App.DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener
{
    public static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(DatePickerFragment).Name.ToUpper();

    Action<DateTime> _dateSelectedHandler = delegate { };

    public static DatePickerFragment NewInstance(Action<DateTime> onDateSelected)
    {
        DatePickerFragment frag = new DatePickerFragment();
        frag._dateSelectedHandler = onDateSelected;

        return frag;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        DateTime currently = DateTime.Now;
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity,
                                                       Resource.Style.MyDialogTheme,
                                                       this,
                                                       currently.Year,
                                                       currently.Month,
                                                       currently.Day);
        dialog.SetTitle("");
        return dialog;
    }

    public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
        _dateSelectedHandler(selectedDate);
    }
}
```

#### Style applied to the DatePickerDialog

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

#### dialog_background drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />

  <corners android:radius="10dp" />

  <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

#### MyDatePicker style definition

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What is  your `MyDatePicker` style?

Comment: I test your code on my device, I cant see the the white border outside of the dialog.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I added the `MyDatePicker` style definition. Have you made sure to apply the `Resource.Style.MyDialogTheme` style on the `DatePickerDialog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue by implementing custom dialogs.

By sub-classing the `Dialog` class, we can create custom dialogs that loads arbitrary `axml` layout files.

This requires you to create an `axml` layout and to define a class, which is obviously more work.

Here is the date picker dialog class I created:

```
public class CustomDatePickerDialog : Dialog
{
    private AltRegisterFormActivity _owner;
    public CustomDatePickerDialog(Context context, int styleId, DateTime birthDate) : base(context, styleId)
    {
        _owner = context as AltRegisterFormActivity;

        SetTitle("");
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DatePickerDialog);
        FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.DialogDatePicker).MaxDate = _getTimeStamp(DateTime.UtcNow.Year - 3);
        FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.DialogDatePicker).MinDate = _getTimeStamp(1920);
        FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.DialogDatePicker).DateTime = birthDate;
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.DialogOkButton).Click += (_, __) =>
        {
            _owner.UISyncContext.Send((state) =>
            {
                _owner.SetDate(FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.DialogDatePicker).DateTime);
                Hide();
            }, null);
        };

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.DialogCancelButton).Click += (_, __) =>
        {
            _owner.UISyncContext.Send((state) =>
            {
                Hide();
            }, null);
        };
    }

    private long _getTimeStamp(int year)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64(new DateTime(year, 1, 1).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

**`CustomDatePickerDialog`'s constructor takes a `styleId` argument that allows to pass the desired style Id.**

And here is the `Resource.Layout.DatePickerDialog` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/date_picker_dialog_padding">
    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/DialogDatePicker"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:calendarViewShown="false" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp">
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:text="CANCEL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/DialogCancelButton"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:text="OK"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/DialogOkButton"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The previous custom dialog will have almost the same look and feel whether it is displayed in a Kitkat or Lollipop+ device.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that I can't get rid of the default background that has a shadowed border when running my application on an Android 4.4.4 device(API 19).
>
> On Android N device (API 25) everything seem to work properly.

It seems that in your `values\styles.xml` file, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` theme in material design support library is not working properly with `DatePickerDialog`.

Your `MyDialogTheme` parent theme is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`, 
 maybe this theme does not work properly for all android versions, it works for `Lollipop` and above but does not work for `KitKat`.

To make it work for both versions you could do this :

- Create a different folder for `values-v21`, copy your `MyDialogTheme` style to  `values-v21\styles.xml` file, then it will  work properly on Android API 21+.
- In your `values\styles.xml` file, define a correct parent of the dialog to make sure it works properly on Android API 19. If you copy `MyDialogTheme` style to  `values-v21\styles.xml` file and delete `MyDialogTheme` style in `values\styles.xml`, effect on Android API 19 like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf3oo.png), maybe this is the effect you want to achieve.

Comment: I worked around the problem by building my dialogs myself by subclassing the `Dialog` class

Comment: @Chedy2149, could you please post the answer so that someone else who have encounter the problem can see the answer?